# In Java, assuming we have a class called Foo, how does obj.getClass().getName() and Foo.class.getName() fetch same results?

Tags: java, class, object

Lets say I have an instance abc of a class called Foo. When I invoke abc.getClass().getName(), I believe I am actually invoking Class"<"Foo">".getName(). So, my question is how is this same as Foo.class.getName() ? Is Foo.class.getName() a native implementation ?

Comment: you call the getClass on the element, being either a class (what class are you ?) or on an instance (of what class are you an instance?) since both are the same, they return the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Foo.class` is a static instance of type `Class<Foo>`; there is only one such instance at runtime.<sup>*</sup>

If `obj` is of type `Foo`, then `obj.getClass()` returns `Foo.class`, by definition.

---

<sub>* This may get weird if you have multiple classloaders, my knowledge gets hazy at that point...</sub>

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense - Foo.class being instance but can instances have a . (dot) in their name ? might be a silly fundamental question.

Comment: @AbhishekPalakkalKaliyath: `Foo.class` is simply an *expression* that evaluates to a reference to the sole `Class<Foo>` instance; it's not a variable name (or similar).

Comment: Thanks for that - so, where does Foo.class live - what holds it - as in which object's instance holds Foo.class ?- Is it JVM ?

Comment: Do such expressions have a name ? Like class symbolication ?

Comment: Oh, yeah ! Class literals !

Answer (score 1):

If you invoke `getClass()` on an instance of `Foo`, the return type is `Class<? extends Foo>`, since the instance might be an instance of a subtype, e.g. `class SubTypeOfFoo extends Foo`.

```
Foo instanceOfFoo = new Foo();
assertEquals(Foo.class, instanceOfFoo.getClass());  // Succeeds
instanceOfFoo = new SubTypeOfFoo();
assertEquals(Foo.class, instanceOfFoo.getClass());  // Fails.
```